# Unable to invalidate low level cache in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, rake

I have a scheduler which invalidates cache by running a rake task.

**app/models/parameter.rb**

```
class Parameter < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :invalidate_bliss_config

  def invalidate_bliss_config
    Parameter.invalidate_config
  end

  def self.bliss_config
    Rails.cache.fetch('bliss_config') { Parameter.first }
  end

  def self.invalidate_config
    Rails.cache.delete('bliss_config')
  end

  def self.auto_change_event_horizon
    Parameter.first.update_attributes!(event_horizon: (Time.zone.today.beginning_of_month + 5.month).end_of_month)
  end
end
```

**config/schedule.rb**

```
set :output, "#{File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))}/../log/cron_log.log"
set :rails_root, "#{File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))}/../"
set :environment, "production"

# Move event horizon on first day  of every month.
every '0 0 1 * *' do
  command "cd #{rails_root} && rvm use 1.9.3 && rvm gemset use rails_3_2_21 && RAILS_ENV=#{environment} bundle exec rake bliss:update_event_horizon"
end
```

**lib/tasks/bliss.rake**

```
namespace :bliss do
  task :update_event_horizon => :environment do
    Parameter.auto_change_event_horizon
  end
end
```

**Update**

**config/environment/development.rb**

```
Bliss::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.whiny_nils = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
end
```

**config/environment/production.rb**

```
Bliss::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.assets.precompile += %w(credit_card_track_parser.js register.js fast_autocompleter.js payment.js)
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
end
```

In UI, we access attribute value using `Parameter.bliss_config.event_horizon`

After running the task if I check value of attribute in UI, it doesn't return latest change. However if I check through `rails console` it returns latest value. If I restart the server, it take latest value(expected!).

**P.S.** 
1. This issue occurs in production only. It works perfectly in development.
2. If I change this config from UI, it takes latest value.

Comment: What cache store are you using? How does your production environment differ from development?

Comment: @FrederickCheung updated question with development and production config.

Comment: You've not said what cache store you're using (if you're not sure, Rails.cache.class will tell you)

Comment: `FileStore` in both environments.

Comment: And all your code has access to the same filesystem ? (For example this is not the case on heroku)

Comment: Yes. Same file system. Same deployment directory.

Comment: What would happen if you change `Rails.cache.fetch('bliss_config') { Parameter.first }` to `Rails.cache.fetch('bliss_config') { Parameter.first.reload }`